# Does not connect to the internet with api 23

Tags: android, permissions

In my application I check the internet connection before entering a fragment, as follows

```
public void goToVirtualConsult (String IdProfesional, String USID) {

        boolean isBackStack=false;

        if (Utils.isConnectingToInternet(MainActivity.this)) {

            final String consultT = "2";
            isBackStack = true;

            setFragmentBackStack5(new VirtualQueryFragment(),Prefs.getString(Constants.USER_ID,""),IdProfesional,USID,consultT);
        }
    }
```

In `Utils`

```
public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            DialogAlert.show_dialog(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.internet_msg));
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
```

In the `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The problem is that I can enter the fragment without problems on a phone with api 24, but with phones with api 23 or 22 I can not enter the fragment because the application crashes. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It should be working, can you edit your question with the stack trace the app is printing to logcat?
Also, you shouldn't only be checking if "ni" is null. This would be a more correct approach: "if (ni == null || !ni.isConnected()) {"

Comment: In physical phone and in the emulator with api 24 it works, the problem is with physical phone or emulator with api 22 or 23.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the stack trace the app is printing to logcat? Without that, it's hard to understand what's really happening.